# Consequences of proposition with existential quantifier

Tags: logic, real-numbers, quantifiers

Independent of axioms you are choosing for constructing reals, the following axiom (or theorem) will be true: $\forall a\not=0,  \exists a^{-1}, a\cdot a^{-1} = 1$. So, basicaly, this axiom allows us to divide (multiply by inverse) by all numbers except $0$. And I intuitively understand how it does this, but the question which arises for me is: "Are we allowed to use in well-formed formulas only objects which exist ?". Because, it is the only way, I see, we can restrict us (using this axiom) from dividing by zero.

Comment: In a well-formed formula we use *symbols* of the relevant language. The language for *reals* has two individual constants : $0$ and $1$. Every interpretation must have two objects that correspond to the two symbols: the axiom $0 \ne 1$ guarantees that they are distinct.

Comment: The quantifier ranges over the objects of the domain of the interpretation: $\forall a \ne 0 \ldots$ is simply : $\forall a (a \ne 0 \to \ldots)$. Thus $\forall a \exists b (a \ne 0 \to a \cdot b =1)$ means that in the said domain for every number different from zero there is a number such that ...

Comment: So, in conclusion: we have *constant* symbols that must have a reference. Thus, the domain of the interpretation must be not-empty ad they must be distincy by axiom $0 \ne 1$. Finally, the quantifiers range over the elements of the domain: thus, they must be interpreted with existsing objects.